# Set Text edittext activity from another class android

Tags: android

I'm a newbie android programmer that want to set text from another class

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler();
reader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);
```

This one another Class but still inside the MainActivity

```
class EventHandler implements RfidEventsListener {
    // Read Event Notification
    public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e){
        TagData[] myTags = myReader.Actions.getReadTags(100);
        if (myTags != null)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());
                //I want to settext here
            }
        }
    }
    // Status Event Notification
    public void eventStatusNotify(RfidStatusEvents e) {
        System.out.println("Status Notification: " + 
        e.StatusEventData.getStatusEventType());
    }
}
```

Thanks.. Regards

Comment: What's exactly wrong with `yourEditText.setText(myText);`?

Comment: What would you like to set the text of? A TextView?

Comment: It's always return "Only the original thread that created view hierarchy can touch its view" @Christopher

Comment: So you just missed to provide us with the most crucial information. :/

Comment: Even though we can see from the code, please always add the language you are using to your question tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only manipulate UI elements, when your code is executed on the UI thread.

```
class EventHandler implements RfidEventsListener {
    // Read Event Notification
    public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e){
        TagData[] myTags = myReader.Actions.getReadTags(100);
        if (myTags != null)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());

                //I want to settext here
                final String myText = myTags[index].getTagID();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myEditText.setText(myText);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
    // Status Event Notification
    public void eventStatusNotify(RfidStatusEvents e) {
        System.out.println("Status Notification: " + 
        e.StatusEventData.getStatusEventType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by: (tested example)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This class was created by Anthony M Cannon on 16/05/2018.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
        handler.test();
    }

    class EventHandler {

        void test() {
            textView.setText("Hello, from EventHandler.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i want the event handler to settext without calling the method from MainActivity

Comment: Yes, it can. I just did you an example to show that a subclass can use variables of its superclass.